# How to understand this collision detection code from a book and point me to the right math?

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection, trigonometry

Please bear with me. I appreciate any pointers / patience and help in understanding the code pasted below.

All the lines marked with the '// ??' comment is where I don't have a clue what's happening.

I picked up the Building an HTML5 Game book (http://buildanhtml5game.com/) in the hopes of learning how to write a game, more especially in HTML5 and JavaScript.

To my surprise, the book does not really explain various background information or assumes the readers already know their way around.

I am not a mathematics expert and that's one big reason I am stuck with the code below. The book barely touches the surface and the explanation is in a line or two (leaving me more confused).

Please, I may ask, do provide me with links so I study the mathematics behind the formulas below and write some English explanation as well so I understand.
I don't want to skip the mathematics parts in this book because it defeats the purpose.

Much appreciated.

```
    var BubbleShoot = window.BubbleShoot || {};
    BubbleShoot.CollisionDetector = (function($){
        var CollisionDetector = {
            findIntersection : function(curBubble,board,angle) {
                // 'angle' is the angle between the 'curBubble' starting bubble
                // at the center of the screen and the mouse click's direction aimed at the bubbles
                // above.
                // I understand how that angle is computed in previous code snippets.

                // 'board' contains an array of bubble objects that are static and laid up on the board
                // waiting to be shot at with 'curbubble' and 'angle'.



                // Get the bubble rows container
                var rows = board.getRows();
                var collision = null;

                // Get the bubble's that will be shot from the center coordinates
                var pos = curBubble.getSprite().position();

                // The start coordinates are the bubble's center
                var start = {
                    left : pos.left + BubbleShoot.ui.BUBBLE_DIMS/2,
                    top : pos.top + BubbleShoot.ui.BUBBLE_DIMS/2
                };

                // ?? (A) what does this give us (mathematically speaking, what are those variables called)
                var dx = Math.sin(angle);
                var dy = -Math.cos(angle);

                for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
                    // for each row
                    var row = rows[i];
                    for(var j=0;j<row.length;j++){
                        // Get bubble at i,j
                        var bubble = row[j];
                        if(bubble){
                            // Get bubble's coordinates. we want to see if the starting bubble
                            // will collidate with this static bubble if the starting bubble was fired
                            // with an angle 'angle'
                            var coords = bubble.getCoords();

                            // ?? (B) that's not the distance between the two points!
                            // ?? what do you call this mathematically?
                            var distToBubble = {
                                x : start.left - coords.left,
                                y : start.top - coords.top
                            };

                            // ?? (C) what is 't'? what does it give? can you please give me reference
                            // ?? so I study the proper math behind its purpose?
                            var t = dx * distToBubble.x + dy * distToBubble.y;

                            // ?? (D) why '-t' * dx and what does this give us?
                            var ex = -t * dx + start.left;
                            // ?? (E) same for 'ey'
                            var ey = -t * dy + start.top;

                            // distance between the two points (ex,ey) and (coords.left,coords.top)
                            // ?? (F) I am not sure what are 'ex' and 'ey'
                            var distEC = Math.sqrt((ex - coords.left) * (ex - coords.left) +
                            (ey - coords.top) * (ey - coords.top));


                            if(distEC<BubbleShoot.ui.BUBBLE_DIMS * .75){
                                // ?? (G) dt is what?
                                var dt = Math.sqrt(BubbleShoot.ui.BUBBLE_DIMS * BubbleShoot.
                                    ui.BUBBLE_DIMS - distEC * distEC);

                                // ?? (H) what's this?
                                var offset1 = {
                                x : (t - dt) * dx,
                                    y : -(t - dt) * dy
                            };
                            // ?? (I) and this?!
                            var offset2 = {
                                x : (t + dt) * dx,
                                y : -(t + dt) * dy
                            };

                            // ?? (J) distance between something
                            var distToCollision1 = Math.sqrt(offset1.x * offset1.x +
                            offset1.y * offset1.y);
                            var distToCollision2 = Math.sqrt(offset2.x * offset2.x +
                            offset2.y * offset2.y);


                            if(distToCollision1 < distToCollision2){
                                var distToCollision = distToCollision1;
                                var dest = {
                                    x : offset1.x + start.left,
                                    y : offset1.y + start.top
                                };
                            }else{
                                var distToCollision = distToCollision2;
                                var dest = {
                                    x : -offset2.x + start.left,
                                    y : offset2.y + start.top
                                };
                            }
                            if(!collision || collision.distToCollision>distToCollision){
                                collision = {
                                    bubble : bubble,
                                    distToCollision : distToCollision,
                                    coords : dest
                                };
                            };
                        };
                    };
                };
            };
        return collision;
    }
    };
    return CollisionDetector;
    })(jQuery);
```

You can play the game here just to see how it looks: http://buildanhtml5game.com/?page_id=20

Comment: (A): Given an angle and a length, you can find the x coordinate by multiplying the length by the sin, and the y coordinate by multiplying it by the cosine.

If you draw a line from the origin to a given point, and think of that as a right triangle (with the line being the hypotenuse and the legs being the x and y distances), the sin and cosine of the angle of the line will give you the proportion that is horizontal or vertical.

(I just re-read this comment and I'm not sure I'm being clear.)

(E) is the pythagorean theorem in reverse.

Comment: Not very clear. (A) and (E) are a good start. I would love a flowing explanation on how (A) to (I) come together. Thanks!